# Could I access variables set by make after make was run?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I have that Makefile that sets up some variables while running, for example `foo = bar`.

When `make` was run, I want to access these variables.

Unfortunately `echo $foo` returns nothing.

Is there a way to export variables from `make` back into the environment?

Comment: like here (http://www.nondot.org/sabre/Mirrored/GNUMake/make_5.html#SEC50)? doesn't work too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but based on the subject line I assume you mean, there's a make variable set in your makefile like `foo = bar`, then after make has run and exited you want to see the value of `foo` in your shell that invoked make?

No, this is not possible.  It has nothing to do with make: it's never possible for a child process of any kind to modify the environment of its parent process (in a POSIX-type system).  The only way this can be done is that the child process generates output that sets the variable, and the parent shell evaluates this output.  So for example, if you wrote a rule in your makefile like this:

```
show-foo: ; @echo 'foo=$(foo)'
```

then you could run this from your shell:

```
eval `make show-foo`
```

and it would set the value in your shell.